# How do I make --import-memory work for WASM compiled by tinygo

Tags: go, webassembly, tinygo

I am trying to compile WASM from go using tinygo for use in go-wasmer. I have the import memory working for AssemblyScript but when I use the flag for the WASM from go and try to create my instance I get this error
`Host env initialization error: Missing export memory`
Is there a way to manually export memory that will then be replaced by the imported memory?
Here is my target.json

```
{
    "inherits": ["wasm"],
    "linker": "wasm-ld",
    "libc": "wasi-libc",
    "goarch": "wasm",
    "cflags": [
        "--target=wasm32--wasi",
        "--sysroot={root}/lib/wasi-libc/sysroot",
        "-Oz"
      ],
    "ldflags": [
        "--import-memory",
        "--max-memory=1310720",
        "--initial-memory=131072"
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Where did you get that `target.json` from, and why do you need it? Just using `-target wasi` should give you something that works.

But more specifically: the error is telling you that `Missing export memory`, but you're trying to `--import-memory`. You can delete the `--import-memory`, and the memory import will turn into an export. If that doesn't work, you should probably paste your code setting up `go-wasmer`. Also, have a look at `wasmer inspect yourbinary.wasm`, to see what's going on with the list of imports and exports.

By the way, by `inherit`ing from `wasm`, you get requirements for nasty Go wasm-js implementation specific imports like `env`.`syscall/js.valueGet`. There are implementations for those ([this](https://github.com/mattn/gowasmer/) e.g.), but since you're already using `wasi`, you can just `inherit` from `wasi` (and delete `goarch`). Your life will probably be easier.

Comment: Do you know if there is a way to limit which memory addresses are available to Go, like some sort of upper bound? I have been using string pointers as returns for my functions in the Go code compiled to WASM and for the most part it works but every now and then I get a string whose pointer is well above the memory limit of the WASM module.

Comment: Comments are not for additional questions. For one, the likelihood of anybody else seeing this comment is low. Better post this as a separate question. Also: No, I don't know. (But eh, it at least explains what you want the `target.json` for. Memory limits.)